# Rank the elements in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

Hi I am working with a `pandas.Dataframe` like below:

```
Name           Quality
Carrot         50
Potato         34
Raddish        43
Ginger         50
Tomato         43
Cabbage        12
```

I want to associate a rank to the dataframe. I have successfully been able to sort the `dataframe` based on the field `Quality` like below:

```
Name           Quality
Carrot         50
Ginger         50
Raddish        43
Tomato         43
Potato         34
Cabbage        12
```

Now what I want to do is, add a new column called `Position` and have the rank at which they exist.

> The point is, the same rank can be given to two different elements if their quality is the same.

**Sample Output Dataframe:**

```
Name           Quality    Position
Carrot         50         1
Ginger         50         1
Raddish        43         2
Tomato         43         2
Potato         34         3
Cabbage        12         4
```

**Notice** how two elements with same quality have the same position while the below elements have +1 position. Also, the dataframe has avg 10 million records

How can I do this in `Pandas.Dataframe`?

I Sort my Dataframe like below:

```
df_sort = dataframe.sort_values(by=attribute, ascending=order)
df_sort.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're going to want to use [Rank](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html).

There are a few variations to rank. The one you want is `Dense`. That ensures that ties don't result in halves.

```
df['Position'] = df.Quality.rank(method='dense', ascending = False).astype(int)
df
      Name  Quality         Position
0   Carrot       50              1
1   Ginger       50              1
2  Raddish       43              2
3   Tomato       43              2
4   Potato       34              3
5  Cabbage       12              4
```

For demonstration purposes, if you didn't use `dense` but rather `min`, your dataframe would look like this:

```
      Name  Quality         Position
0   Carrot       50              1
1   Ginger       50              1
2  Raddish       43              3
3   Tomato       43              3
4   Potato       34              5
5  Cabbage       12              6
```

The key here is to use `ascending = False`

Comment: just what I was looking for. Two questions, 1) can I get the rank to be an `int` instead of `float`? 2) `df.Quality` refers to the column name right? Can I do a df['Quality'] as well?

Comment: A matter of taste but `axis=0` is the default value and could be left out. Might want to throw in a `.astype(int)` to match their expected output as well.

Comment: @iam.Carrot yes you can. If, for instance, your column header had a space in it, it's easier to put it in brackets. Both methods work however.

Answer (score 0):

For a pre-sorted dataframe, you can use [`pandas.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df['Rank'] = pd.factorize(df['Quality'])[0] + 1

print(df)

      Name  Quality  Rank
0   Carrot       50     1
1   Ginger       50     1
2  Raddish       43     2
3   Tomato       43     2
4   Potato       34     3
5  Cabbage       12     4
```

Comment: Is it faster than the below answer? Or would a `df.Rank` would better than the `factorize`

Comment: @iam.Carrot, I see `factorize` faster for a pre-sorted dataframe. But test with your data. It also doesn't require conversion to `int`. `rank` has more features, which you may or may not need.

Comment: I've added the code that I use to sort it based on a few fields.

Comment: @iam.Carrot, I trust you've sorted correctly. You should test performance with your data. `rank` or `factorize` will work.